# Cleaning a Custom User Model

Tags: django

I have just created a custom user model and am unsure as to where I should put the code which cleans it. For example, right now the email field is unique however it is case-sensitive which it shouldn't be, where would I put the code which cleans this? Another example, I want to have checks to ensure the password is greater than a certain length etc. where should I put this code? Any advice is appreciated! Cheers

Code
Models -

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False,
                                 **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True,
                                 **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('staff status', default=False,
        help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.')
    is_active = models.BooleanField('active', default=True,
        help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('date joined', default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

Forms -

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = []

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = []
```

Admin -

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')}),
    )

    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    ordering = ('email',)

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: for field validation, you need to put the clean function inside form class.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean alot of repeating myself? Also wouldn't it not call the function when creating or editing a user in the admin panel?

Comment: Django 1.9 has built in [password validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation). If you are subclassing Django's authentication forms, then hopefully all you need to do is set `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`.

Comment: What would I do about the email issue though?

Comment: Case sensitive user emails is tricky. You might find [these](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/SW7_qI81G58/Mdw65BhEBAAJ) [posts](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/a4I7rHuT4Dw/cc0VNzjwEAAJ) about case sensitive usernames on the django-developers group useful.

Comment: So in general various validation for a custom user model will go in the forms?

Comment: The values are validated in the forms. However, note that some of the rules for validation are specified in the models (e.g. `max_length`, `unique`), and some are specified in your site settings (e.g. `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATIONS`).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for showing the code.

1. For the email issue you have 2 ways to go about it, at the `Form` level and at the `Model` level.

- For the `Form` solution:

In both Creation and Change form classes (I'd suggest the terms Create and Update) add the following method:

```
def clean_email(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['email']
    data = data.lower()
    # Always return a value to use as the new cleaned data
    return data
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

- For the `Model` solution:

Add the following methods to your custom User class:

```
    def clean(self):
        # This method can be used to raise non field specific ValidationErrors or cleaning the data.
        if (self.email){
            self.email = self.email.lower()
        }

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # This overriding of the save method is necessary because Django by default does not call the
        # full_clean() method and there is where the clean() method is called
        self.full_clean()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

2. Regarding the  Password length issue, as mentioned in the comments by @alasdair, you can use the out of the box django `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`. To be more specific you can edit them at your project django settings file, `settings.py` by default they have something like:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

The second validator called `MinimumLengthValidator` has by default a minimum length of 8 characters. But, you can override this by adding an options dict like this:

```
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    'OPTIONS': {
       'min_length': 9,
    }
}
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#enabling-password-validation